# how to upload a file to s3 and make it readable by "everyone", in one linux command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scripting

I want to upload test.zip to mybucket1 folder1 test.zip
and set the permission to "allow read" for "Everyone"

Can this be done with a single linux command?

Answer (score 0):

sure it can be, though i dont really understand if you want to upload or just move so i am going for one of these.

```
mv test.zip /mybucket1/folder1 | chmod 644 test.zip
```

with using the 644 you define these permissions for the file.

```
-rw-r--r--
```

if you want this: `-rwxr--r--`
instead of `644` add `744`.

Comment: mybucket1 is the name of a remote folder (s3 bucket), i didn't mean a local folder.